# Audit.net with azure table storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, audit.net

How can i store audit data in azure table storage,audit.net provides (https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#data-providers-included)
sqldataprovider only can you please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Write your own `AuditDataProvider` - https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET.SqlServer/Providers/SqlDataProvider.cs

Comment: Hi alex I created a custom audit data provider,thanks for help.

Comment: I will create a configurable Azure Table data provider soon and add it as an extension. Actually it will be part of the `Audit.NET.AzureStorage` package.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the [Azure Table data provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET.AzureStorage/Providers/AzureTableDataProvider.cs) to store your audit events on azure tables. It is included from version 12.1.9 on the [Audit.NET.AzureStorage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Audit.NET.AzureStorage/) package.

You can configure the columns dynamically via an anonymous object or dictionary, or implementing your own [TableEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity?view=azure-dotnet) class.

For example:

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseAzureTableStorage(_ => _
        .ConnectionString("your cnn string")
        .TableName("Events")
        .EntityBuilder(e => e
            .PartitionKey($"Events{ev.StartDate:yyyyMM}")
            .Columns(c => c.FromObject(ev => new 
            { 
                Date = ev.StartDate, 
                User = ev.Environment.UserName, 
                ... 
            }))));
```

Take a look at the README file [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET.AzureStorage/README.md).

For further problems, note you can also [open an issue](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/new/choose) instead of asking on SO. or ask on the [Audit.NET Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/Audit-NET/Lobby)

Comment: Thanks @thepirat000,but i wrote my custom provider       Audit.Core.Configuration.DataProvider = new AzureTableDataprovider()
            {
                ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuditDbConnection"].ToString(),
                Schema = "dbo",
                TableName = "tblbateventsauditing",
                IdColumnName = "EventId",
                JsonColumnName = "Data"
            };

Answer (score 0):

```
  Audit.Core.Configuration.DataProvider = new AzureTableDataprovider()
        {
            ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuditDbConnection"].ToString(),
            Schema = "dbo",
            TableName = "tblbateventsauditing",
            IdColumnName = "EventId",
            JsonColumnName = "Data"
        };
```